# Why I cannot validate User ID?

Tags: javascript, html, web-deployment

Here I tried to validate the User Id using JavaScript for a form. But I could not get the expected message. You can see my code below the description. can you help me to find the wrong that I have done?

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function formValidation(uid) {
            var numbers = /^[0-9]/;
            if (uid.value == "") {
                alert('Empty values are not allowed.');
                return false;
            }
            else if (numbers.test(uid.value) == false) {
                alert('Please input numbers only');
                return false;
            }
            else if (userid_validation(uid, 5, 12) == false) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;

            }
        }
        function userid_validation(uid, mx, my) {
            var uid_len = uid.value.length;
            if (uid_len == 0 || uid_len >= my || uid_len < mx) {
                alert("length be between " + mx + " to " + my);
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" onsubmit="return formValidation(this)">

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    *Enter valid ID :
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="userid"></input>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</body>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `uid` supposed to be? Also to make your code readable, use the stackoverflow snippet tool to paste your code if the code block isn't too good for you

Answer (score 1):

Your uid OBJECT is equal to the form element. To get the input value you need to assign an id for it. and also the RegEx for numbers /^[0-9]/ main that any input starting with number it will return true for (12ABCD). To get only numbers use /^\d+$/ or /^[0-9]+/.

```
<script>
        function formValidation(uid) {
            var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
            if (uid.userid.value == "") {
                alert('Empty values are not allowed.');
                return false;
            }
            else if (numbers.test(uid.userid.value) == false) {
                alert('Please input numbers only');
                return false;
            }
            return (userid_validation(uid, 5, 12));
        }

        function userid_validation(uid, mx, my) {
            var uid_len = uid.userid.value.length;
            if (uid_len >= my || uid_len < mx) {
                alert("length be between " + mx + " to " + my);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

   </script>
```

I add the id="userid" in input tag.

```
    <form name="form1" onsubmit="return formValidation(this)">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    *Enter valid ID :
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="userid" id="userid"></input>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```